# Issue faced on GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined during ansible container build

Tags: docker, module, build-error, relocation, ansible-container

Code :     container.yml

```
version: '2'
settings:
conductor_base: centos:7
services:
ansible.play_container:
from: "play:8_jre_security"
roles:
- play_container
ports:
- "9000:9000"
user: play
command: ['app/xxx/docker-entrypoint.sh']
registries: {}

OS / ENVIRONMENT Details :

Ansible Container, version 0.9.2
Linux, 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64, #1 SMP Mon Feb 29 13:22:02 EST 2016, x86_64
2.7.5 (default, May 3 2017, 07:55:04)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] /usr/bin/python
```

Command Used : sudo ansible-container --debug build

```
Error Log: 
 Fatal: [ansible.play_container]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "/_usr/bin/python: relocation error: /_usr/lib64/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/tmpXAGeVC/playbook.retry
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ansible.play_container     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
2017-11-28T06:09:14.110001 Error applying role!           [container.core] caller_file=/_ansible/container/core.py caller_func=apply_role_to_container caller_line=699 engine=<container.docker.engine.Engine object at 0x7fbcfd43ce90> exit_code=2 playbook=[{'hosts': u'ansible.play_container', 'roles': ['play_container'], 'vars': {}}]
```

Please check and help on steps to resolve the relocation error

Answer (score 1):

The conductor base image and the target container base image need to derive from the same distro. I'm guessing whatever `play:8_jre_security` is, it's not a CentOS 7 derived image.